# Xamarin, Button bug while using transparent background [Image]

Tags: button, background, xamarin.forms

As you can see, button has an unexpected behavior when is pressed on Android!

```
<Button
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       Text="English"
       Clicked="English_OnClicked"
       Style="{StaticResource wizardButton}"/>
```

App.Xml:

```
<Style x:Key="wizardButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3FFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#FFFF" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#CFFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2" />
        </Style>
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource grayDark}" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="50" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Also I checked it on real devices and same result!
Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.4.267
The Build Target is 7.1

[image]

Comment: Can you share this in any one editor? like jsfiddle or codeopen

Comment: @MaheswaranS Why should I share this simple **C#** code via these services? I don't understand the purpose of this

Comment: Did you mean the style of french button?

Comment: @MaheswaranS, Yes I did, I pressed this one

Comment: I thought, some CSS default animation properties applying for these button.